# Set single raster to NA where values of raster stack are NA

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have two 30m x 30m raster files which I would like to sample points from.  Prior to sampling, I would like to remove the clouded areas from the images.  I turned to R and Hijman's Raster package for the task.

Using the drawPoly(sp=TRUE) command, I drew in 18 different polygons.  The function did not seem to allow 18 polygons as one sp object, so I drew them all separately.  I then gave the polygons a proj4string matching the rasters', and set them into a list.  I ran the list through a lapply function to convert them to rasters (rasterize function in Hijman's package) with the polygon areas set to NA, and the rest of the image set to 1.

My end goal is one raster layer with the 18 areas set to NA.  I have tried stacking the list of rasterized polygons, and subsetting it to put set a new raster to NA in the same areas.  My reproducible code is below.

```
library(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrow=50, ncol = 50)
r1[] <- 1
r1[4:10,] <- NA
r2 <- raster(nrow=50, ncol = 50)
r2[] <- 1
r2[9:15,] <- NA
r3 <- raster(nrow=50, ncol = 50)
r3[] <- 1
r3[24:39,] <- NA

r4 <- raster(nrow=50, ncol = 50)
r4[] <- 1

s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)

test.a.cool <- calc(s, function(x){r4[is.na(x)==1] <- NA})
```

For whatever reason, the darn testacool is a blank plot, where I'm aiming to have it as a raster with all values except for the NAs in the stack, s, equal to 1.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `sum(s)` will work, as `sum()` returns `NA` for any grid cell with even one `NA` value in the stack.

To see that it works, compare the figures produced by the following:

```
plot(s)
plot(sum(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

I posted this question on the R-Sig-Geo forum, as well, and received a response from the package author.  The two simplest solutions:

Use the sp package to rbind my polygons into one, then rasterize the polygon.

```
p <- rbind(p1, p2, p3...etc., makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)

r4 <- raster(nrow=50, ncol = 50)
r4[] <- 1
mask <- rasterize(p, r4)
mask[mask %in% 1:18] <- 1
#The above code produces a single raster file with 
#my polygons as unique values, ready for masking.
```

And the second simple solution, as just pointed out by Josh O'Brien:

```
m <- sum(s)
test <- mask(r4, m)
```

The R community rocks.  Problem solved (twice) within an hour.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was right now in the process of editing my answer to note that this farther upstream solution is in fact the better way to solve your problem, but you saved me the effort!

Comment: As I look closer at the response and package PDF, don't even need to rasterize the polygon.  You can use the mask function in raster package with a spatial polygon.

Comment: No prob. By the way, if you've drawn a **bunch** of polygons and have them all in a list (as a result of doing, say `x <- lapply(1:40, drawPoly)`), the following will be an equivalent but cleaner way to combine them into a single SpatialPolygons object: `do.call(rbind, c(x, makeUniqueIDs=TRUE))`. i.e. that'll be easier and less error-prone than typing `rbind(x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]], ..., x[[40]], makeUniqueIDs=TRUE)` .

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the package you are using, however looking at the final line in your code, I think the issue might be here:

```
 function(x){r4[is.na(x)==1] <- NA})
```

It doesn't look like `calc` will do much with that. It is setting the values of `r4` indexed by the `NA`s of `x` and setting those to `NA`.

What then?   If anything, maybe:

```
 function(x){r4[is.na(x)==1] <- NA; return(r4) })
```

Although, it's not clear if that is even what you are after.

Comment: Sure, makes sense.  That was my first code, which produces this error "Error in setValues(out, x) : 
  values must be numeric, integer, logical or factor", which is an error derived from the raster package, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: if `r4` is a `raster` object, can it be assigned logical `NA` values?  That aside, there is no point in having a function that does nothing simply because it was giving you an error ;)

Comment: For whatever reason, this works:  r4[is.na(r2)==1] <- NA, but this doesnt r4[is.na(s)==1] <- NA

Comment: Well, start by determining the differences between `r2` and `s` and I'm certain that will lead you to your answer.   Useful tools are `str(.)`, `dput()` `is()`.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track. The `[` operator is defined for rasters and raster stacks, so you could just use the single line:

```
r4[ any(is.na(s) ) ] <- NA
plot(r4)
```

If you wanted to use `calc` you could have used it like this:

```
r4 <- calc( s, function(x){ ( ! any( is.na(x) ) ) } )
r4[is.na(r4)] <- NA
plot(r4)
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon.  Calc would have been the right move since I have a 12,000,000 cells in each raster layer, right?  I think I read that arithmetic operators can freeze up on large datasets.

Comment: Yes `calc` is the way to go because it will operate on large datasets in chunks. I am curious, does `sum` work on raster layers that big?

Comment: It's summing a stack with nlayers=12, ncell = 12,072,775 in less than a minute.  Impressive.

Comment: Using sum inside `calc` or just using `sum(s)`? It's good to know because I often work with large rasters and I'd normally plump for `calc` but I can't see in this case why it would perform better than a simple call to `sum` as Josh recommends.

Comment: That was just using the sum() function, as per Josh's rec.